# Mistake in integration of $\sec(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

I wanted to find the integral of $\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}= \sec(2x)+\tan(2x)$ from $0-\frac{3\pi}{2}$. I calculated the second one as $0$ so my problem is calculating the first one.  I wrote it as $\frac{\sec^2(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}$ now putting $\tan(x)=u$ the numerator is $du$ so we get $0.5(\frac{1}{1-u}+\frac{1}{1+u})$ after using Partial fractions .So integral becomes $0.5\ln(\frac{1+\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)})$ after using log property.But then we get answer as $\infty$ while the answer should be $0$

Comment: Notice that there is a discontinuity at $\frac{3\pi}{4}$

Comment: "The answer should be 0" says who?  Near $x = 3\pi/4$ the function diverges like $- \sqrt{2} / (x - 3\pi/4)$. Your function is not even integrable.

Comment: The answer sheet given to me

Comment: Moreover, that fraction doesn't equal $\sec (2x)+\tan (2x) $

Comment: @WillFisher: in the scheme of things, the minus sign is inconsequential (in multiple ways) :-)

Comment: Whoever prepared that answer sheet needs a refresher course in [improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, for the undefinite integral. Substutite $u=2x$ and $\text{d}u=2\space\text{d}x$:

$$\int\sec(2x)\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int\sec(x)\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Now, multiply numerator and denominator by $\tan(u)+\sec(u)$:

---

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sec^2(u)+\sec(u)\tan(u)}{\sec(u)+\tan(u)}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substutite $s=\tan(u)+\sec(u)$ and $\text{d}s=(\sec^2(u)+\sec(u)\tan(u))\space\text{d}u$:

---

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{s}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\ln\left|s\right|}{2}+\text{C}=\frac{\ln\left|\tan(2x)+\sec(2x)\right|}{2}+\text{C}$$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar You're welcome, I'm glad that I could help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to evaluate
$$I=\int\frac {\cos x -\sin x}{\cos x +\sin x}dx$$
Set $m=\cos x +\sin x$, $dm=\cos x -\sin x dx $
$$I=\int\frac {1}{m}dm=\ln |\cos x +\sin x|+C$$
Then the definite integral is
$$I\Bigr|_0^{3\pi/2}=\ln|-1|-\ln|1|=0$$

Comment: Make it  $|...|$

Comment: Realized that mistake. My bad

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int \frac{\cos x - \sin x}{\sin x + \cos x} \, dx = \int \frac{du} u
$$
where $u= \sin x + \cos x$.